Excel no actualiza dato de una celda con update, cuando este archivo fue creado con xlworkbook c#
Tengo un problema con un código, he creado un archivo excel que tomó datos de un datagridview, el cual si lo hace sin problemas, pero al momento de el archivo creado lo tomo para hacerle un update utilizando el oledbconnection, pasa algo bien raro, va y borra el dato en la celda pero no actualiza la información que le he dado en el set.
este es el codigo que utilizo para hacer el update.
using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source=" + Ruta 2 + ";Extended Properties='Excel 12.0;HDR=1;IMEX=0;'"))
{
    try
    {
        conn.Open();
        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
        cmd.Connection = conn;
        cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE [Tablero$] SET [SINVALIDAR] = 'VALIDADO' where [PrefixBaseSuffix] = '" + tb_componente.Text + "'";
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex + "");
    }
    finally
    {
        conn.Close();
        conn.Dispose();
    }
}

¿Como le puedo hacer para hacer el update?, o si hay otra manera. Gracias.
